# Is there a way to make an absoulte shapes fixed when using KeyboardAvoidingView for both IOS & Android in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to make some absoulte shapes in the background fixed while using KeyboardAvoidingView, so all elements moves except those shapes since it does not matter if the keybored cover them. Is there a way to implement that without external packages